# Jupyter Notebook download to other format not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandoc, nbconvert

I am using Jupyter on Linux, Jupyter itself is working fine, I need to download my notebook to pdf through the Jupyter menu. I tried following the error message to install pandoc, ...., just not successful, still error out like below:

> nbconvert failed: pandoc wasn't found.

I already installed both nbconvert and pandoc though.

Thanks.